# Datetime comparision with JSON is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with JSON data. JSON has a property with value '2023-10-05T22:34:13.7944869+00:00'. In my SQL where clause if I write below code it doesn't return any records.

```
JSON_VALUE( myrow.Value,'$.Date') 
BETWEEN '2023-10-05 00:00:00' AND '2023-10-05 23:59:59')
```

However if I change the date in the where clause to 6th Oct like below it returns records.

```
JSON_VALUE( myrow.Value,'$.Date') 
BETWEEN '2023-10-05 00:00:00' AND '2023-10-06 23:59:59')
```

As JSON has 5th Oct date why first condition is not returning data.

Comment: What's your timezone.  Your sample time is a GMT time.

Comment: Your comparison is a local time.

Comment: Json has date value in UTC, SQL server database timestamp in PST

Comment: Why not use `OPENJSON` and then you can define it's a date and time value in the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

```
CONVERT(datetime2,JSON_VALUE( myrow.Value,'$.Date'),126)
```